# KeyEvent doesn't understand TAB key

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, keyevent

Sorry about the question.I guess some people have asked this before but the format of their questions and hence the answers where in a way that I didnt understand.(I'm an amateur)
the problem is that KeyEvent doesnt understand when TAB key is pressed.
PS:I'm creating a notepad using JFrame as an assignment.
thanks in advance.

```
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_TAB) {

        AdvancedChar c = new AdvancedChar('\t');
        frame.wholeText.linesList.get(frame.cursor.j).chars.add(frame.cursor.i, c);
        System.out.println("tab pressed");
        frame.repaint();
    }
```

PS2:people have mentioned using             frame.setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS);
in the answers related to this question.but I have no idea how to set this method in my code.

Comment: What are you using as your base component?  You may find that the tab key is been consumed

Comment: what do you mean by base component?sorry as I mentioned im an amateur. I'm using KeyListener and JFrame as classes

Comment: What component are you using to monitor key event against?  I'm assuming something like `JTextArea`, in which case the `tab` key already has a key binding associated against it which inserts a tab/spaces into the components `Document`

Comment: no we're not allowed to use JTextArea

Comment: The what are you binding the key listener to?

Comment: KeyListener accepts an object of JFrame as an argument